How to trigger even in checklist when we close the checklist in productfruit
I am working on productfruit checklist, i have used in my website, it is working, what I want is that, when we close the checklist, it is asking me two option "Yes" or "No", what I want if I will click on the "Yes" option I want event of that, can anyone please help me how to do that, any help will be really appreciated, here is my code for that
if (window.productFruits.api.checklists) {
    console.log(window.productFruits.api.checklists);

    try {
        window.productFruits.api.checklists.injectToElement(checklistId, yourElement, { checkEligibility: true });
        backgroundBlur.style.display = 'block';
    } catch (e) {
        console.error('Error injecting checklist:', e.message);
    }
} else {
    console.error('checklistsFactory is not available.');
}

